# Getting all combinations in R, repetition allowed

Tags: r, combinations

The built-in `combn` only gives half the combinations:

```
> t(combn(1:5, 2))
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    1    3
 [3,]    1    4
 [4,]    1    5
 [5,]    2    3
 [6,]    2    4
 [7,]    2    5
 [8,]    3    4
 [9,]    3    5
[10,]    4    5
```

For example there is no (1,1) nor (2,1).

How can I get all combinations?

Comment: May be `expand.grid(rep(list(1:5),2))`

Comment: You can also use `CJ` from `data.table` for fast combination.

Comment: `combn` by definition just gives you the upper-triangle of the combination matrix, to avoid repetition. Not the diagonal and not the lower-triangle.

Comment: FYI, this is called the *Cartesian product* of `1:5` and `1:5`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @akrun said, it looks like `expand.grid` will do it.

```
> expand.grid(rep(list(1:5), 2))
   Var1 Var2
1     1    1
2     2    1
3     3    1
4     4    1
5     5    1
6     1    2
7     2    2
8     3    2
9     4    2
10    5    2
11    1    3
12    2    3
13    3    3
14    4    3
15    5    3
16    1    4
17    2    4
18    3    4
19    4    4
20    5    4
21    1    5
22    2    5
23    3    5
24    4    5
25    5    5
```

Answer (score 3):

You could get the Cartesian product using `merge`:

```
merge(1:5, 1:5)
```

Output:

```
   x y
1  1 1
2  2 1
3  3 1
4  4 1
5  5 1
6  1 2
7  2 2
8  3 2
9  4 2
10 5 2
11 1 3
12 2 3
13 3 3
14 4 3
15 5 3
16 1 4
17 2 4
18 3 4
19 4 4
20 5 4
21 1 5
22 2 5
23 3 5
24 4 5
25 5 5
```

Using `sqldf`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5)
df2 <- df1
sqldf("SELECT df1.a, df2.a FROM df1 
      CROSS JOIN df2")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually called as permutations with repeated elements. Besides the given recommendations, you can use `gtools::permutations` function:

```
gtools::permutations(5, 2, 1:5, repeats.allowed=TRUE)
```

Comment: I think this should be `gtools::combinations(5, 2, 1:5, repeats.allowed=TRUE)` to follow definition of combinations with repetition allowed, i.e., \binom{n+k-1}{k}